# What's the point of setting View's alpha to 0 when it's off the screen?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

In many [ViewPager's examples](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide) there is setting page's alpha to 0 when it's slided out of screen like:

```
if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
    // This page is way off-screen to the left.
    view.setAlpha(0f);
}
```

I can't figure out what is the point of doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of the documentation it is because they are using it for animation.

If you want to do any kind of fadein/zoomin animation, you may want to start your animation with a completely invisible page.